# How make complex request in jdbc?

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb

I want to get random name from database.

```
@Override
    public String createName() {
        String result = "empty";
        String sqlSelect;
        sqlSelect = "select * from names";
        String sqlOrderBy = "ORDER BY RAND()";
        String sqlLimit = "Limit 1";

        try {
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sqlSelect + " ; " + sqlOrderBy + " + " + sqlLimit);
            //resultSet.getString("name");
            System.out.println("Random name from database: " + resultSet.getString("name"));
            result = resultSet.getString("name");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I don't know how to create request rightly. I'm a beginner in jdbc

Comment: Before posting, thoroughly search Stack Overflow. You would have found *many* existing Answers with example code to study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your question is the String you pass to executeQuery.
It actually translates to this `select * from names ; ORDER BY RAND() + Limit 1`

But it should look like this `select * from names ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;`

So adapt this row

`resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sqlSelect + " ; " + sqlOrderBy + " + " + sqlLimit);`

to:

`resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sqlSelect + " " + sqlOrderBy + " " + sqlLimit+";");`

Additionally, you should close all resources or swap to a [try with resources block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Edit: there are still a few things wrong or should be optimized

```
@Override
    public String createName() {
        String result = "empty";
        String sqlSelect;
        sqlSelect = "select * from names";
        String sqlOrderBy = "ORDER BY RAND()";
        String sqlLimit = "Limit 1";

        try (
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sqlSelect + " " + sqlOrderBy + " " + sqlLimit+";"))
        {
            while(restultSet.next(){
                result = resultSet.getString("name");
                System.out.println("Random name from database: " + result);
            }
            

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I switched to try with resources, so you do not have to worry about closing them since they implement the [AutoClosable Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html).
Additionally you didn't mention ResultSet and Statement as variable type which makes me think that you declared it somewhere at class level. That would be a bad idea.

Edit2:
You should also use the `while(ResultSet.next())` this moves the "cursor" forward and you can access the first element. If your resultset would return more rows, then it iterates over all rows and you can deal with the data in that block.